# Inject JSF request parameter in a bean managed by Spring using annotations

Tags: java, spring, jsf

Right now I use the `f:viewParam` tag to inject the request parameter into a field of my bean

```
<f:viewParam name="id" value="#{surveyController.id}" />
```

But I would much rather prefer to use annotations for this. I know about the `@Value` annotation, and I guess I could do something like this

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
public class SurveyControlador {
    @Value("#{new Long.parseLong('${param.id}')}")
    private Long id;

    ....
}
```

But this is just plain ugly.

Is there a better way, where I don't need to convert the value explicitly, and maybe even omit the "param"? I'm even willing to install third party libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used omnifaces' [@Param](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/Param) successfully, like so:

```
@Named @ViewScoped
public class SurveyController {
    @Inject @Param(name = "id")
    private ParamValue<Long> idParam;

    public void doStuff() {
        if (idParam.getValue().equals(1)) {
            throw new IllegalAccessException("you don't dare");
        }
    }
}
```

**Pro:** You additionally get access to the raw submitted value and omnifaces optionally applies validations/conversions (check the docs).

**Con:** Wrapper around your real parameter. And you still need to specify `<f:viewParam>` (you don't need to bind it to a backing bean, tho) if you want to keep the parameter for navigation.

Note that this leverages CDI, which may or may not fit the way you do things.

Comment: Yes, I know about Omnifaces' @Param annotation, but I have to use Spring for dependency injection per user requirement :( Thank you anyways, mabi

Comment: Too bad, then. Never done much Spring, so I have to leave it to others to give a better solution.